# Best way to validate in Javascript that response is from my server(s)?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, security

I have some values being sent from a server as a JSON object to a JS client. What is the best way for the client to validate that the response did indeed come from my server? I want to prevent users from using the client to connect to a different server.

I am aware that a user can change the JS of any page, but I expect that looking through thousands of lines of obfuscated JS is much harder than just setting up a fake response to pass new values into a client. Verifying the response is just an extra layer of security. It is not intended to provide perfect security, but simply an extra layer of protection against misuse.

Comment: What is your threat model? Are you trying to defend against a man-in-the-middle attack altering messages sent to an honest user, or are you trying to defend against actual users abusing your client?

Comment: @apsillers abusing the client, sending in different values to manipulate the app

Comment: A user can easily change the code of the *client page itself*. If you write code to check that the data is genuine, a user could simply edit the page to remove the code that performs that check.

Comment: @apsillers absolutely. But surely looking through thousands of lines of obfuscated JS is much harder than just setting up a fake response to pass new values into a client? The client needs to ask the server for any updates to its values (it's for a game). Verifying the response is just an extra layer of security and I want to see if this is actually possible. This isn't an issue for the unity client but wanted to see how far I can get for the WebGL client.

Comment: I edited your question to include the information you've provided in the comments. If you don't like it, feel free to edit it further, or roll it back.

Comment: @apsillers no, that's all good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if the server includes a hash of the response using something unique to that client (a session token perhaps?) then the client verifies the hash against the expected hash to ensure the response wasn't tampered?

Comment: @apokryfos yep, this is my current thought too. I like the HMAC way of doing it but either using a HMAC, or a session token as you suggested, a token or secret key would need to be stored on the client which, for a web client written in JS, is basically public. It'd be too expensive to encrypt/decrypt on every request. I wondered about changing the tokens based on time?! Just trying to find the best way of doing it.. Your method is the best way I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @Matt Yes indeed the token is public, I'm suggesting it though because a lot of server side frameworks include a cross-site request forgery validation based on such a token so in theory the server would have already validated that the client has the correct token based on the server's internal session identifier. This way anyone else acquiring this token would have to also hijack the user's session which is harder to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL for this. If your JS client validates the server SSL certificate, you will know for sure that the response is truly from your server.

Comment: That doesn't prevent the user from changing the code to get the answers from a _different server_.  It only confirms that _someone_ was willing to supply an SSL certificate for whatever server they reached.